# How to create a function that expects a Integral List

Tags: haskell

So I'm learning Haskell for school and was learning about functions, syntax and typeclasses over at learnyouahaskell and was wondering I would create a function that takes in an Integral list as a parameter?

If I'm understanding this correctly:

```
addVectors :: (Num a) => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> (a,a)
addVectors (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
```

addVectors takes in two sets that basically all parameters have to be of the Number class? But what about if I want it to take in a list of Numbers or Integrals?

```
addList :: (Integral [b]) => [b] -> [b]
```

But this clearly didn't work.

Comment: So I figured part of it out.

    `addList :: (Integral b) => [b] -> [b]`
    `addList (x:xs) = x + 1 : addList xs`

But now I get an exhaustive pattern error. How do I fix that?

Comment: Tell it what to do with an empty list.

Comment: You want to increment *all* elements with one?

Comment: Yep! `addList [] = []` Thanks!

Comment: `addList = map (+1)`

Comment: Haven't learn about mapping yet, but it's coming up. Thanks!

Comment: `map` is basically "apply this operation to all elements of the list".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
addList :: (Integral b) => [b] -> [b]
```

Here we're saying that the `b` type must be an instance of `Integral`, and that `addList` takes and returns a list of `b`s.

Comment: So I wrote it two different ways and was wondering which would be considered better:

`addList xs = [x + 1 | x <- xs]` non-recursive 

or

`addList [] = []
addList (x:xs) = x + 1 : addList xs`

The first one doesn't require that guard.

Comment: @humbleCoder Given a choice between those, I would prefer the first (list comprehension) version, because it abstracts some details away: You can immediately see that it iterates over the input list and you don't have to figure out what exactly the recursion does. But in practice I'd write it as `addList xs = map (+ 1) xs`, because it's even more direct: We want to apply the same operation (`+ 1`) to each element of the list and return a list of results.

Comment: Understood. I'm assuming the xs at the end of the function is the return statement essentially? Also, I don't understand why this post was down voted and now it's at -1.

Answer (score 3):

`Integral a`, means that `a` is an integral, and that you can perform functions on `a`s, like `div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`.

So if you want a list `[a]` of `Integral`s, that means that `a` should be `Integral`. So you should write:

```
addList :: Integral b => [b] -> b
```

Furthermore note that the output type is probably a `b`, since you "fold the list together to one such number.

In case you want to increment for instance all number (or perform another operation on the numbers), the type is:

```
addList :: Integral b => [b] -> [b]
```

since now we specify that the output is a list of `b`s.